# Wordpress Bootstrap tabs not showing post limit

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've set my loop to display 5 posts for each tab (category). But it's not doing that, even when there are 5 or more posts in a category. It won't do more than 4. I'm not sure why. Following is my code (I'm using ACF to choose which categories to display from the backend). Any help would be appreciated (note also that I'm formatting the first item in each tab differently):

```
<!-- Nav Tabs -->
<ul  class="nav nav-pills">
    <?php if (have_rows('home_categories')) {
        $i = 0;
        while (have_rows('home_categories')) {
            the_row();
            $term = get_sub_field('categories'); ?>
    <li class="<?php if ($i == 0) { echo ' active'; }?>"> 
        <a href="#tab-pane-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
    </li>
        <?php $i++;
        }
    } ?>
</ul>

<!-- Tab Content -->
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <?php $home_categories = get_field("home_categories");

        foreach($home_categories as $key => $home_cat) {
            $term_id = $home_cat['categories']->term_id;
            $term_name = $home_cat['categories']->name;
    ?>
    <div class="tab-pane fade<?php if ($key == 0) { echo ' in active'; }?>" id="tab-pane-<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <div class="posts-box row">
            <div class="box-content">
                <ul>
                    <?php $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                                'terms' => array($term_id)
                            )
                        ),
                        'posts_per_page' => 5,
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    $count = 0;

                    foreach($query->posts as $post) {
                        $count++;
                        if ($count == 1) {
                    ?>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <li class="first-news clearfix">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="bookmark">
                                <?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
                                <div class="post-thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $feat_image; ?>); height: 200px; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">

                                    <span class="fa overlay-icon"></span>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                            <a title="<?php the_title($post->ID) ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                <h3 class="post-box-title"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></h3>
                            </a>

                            <p class="post-meta">
                                <span class="darwin-date">
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                    <?php echo get_the_date($post->ID); ?>
                                </span>

                                <span class="post-comments">
                                    <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_comments_link( $post->ID ); ?>">
                                        <?php comments_number( '0' , '1' , '%' ); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </p>

                            <div class="entry">
                                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words($post->post_content, 20, '...'); ?></p>

                                <div class="more-posts">
                                    <a class="more-link" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip">Read More &raquo;</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="container-fluid">

                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <li class="other-news row">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="bookmark">
                                    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $feat_image; ?>); height: 100px; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
                                        <span class="fa overlay-icon"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>

                                <div class="news-info col-md-9">
                                    <h4 class="post-box-title">
                                        <a title="<?php the_title($post-ID) ?>" href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a>
                                    </h4>

                                    <p class="post-meta">
                                        <span class="darwin-date">
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                            <?php echo get_the_date($post->ID); ?>
                                        </span>

                                        <span class="post-cats">
                                            <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                                            <?php printf('%1$s', get_the_category_list(', ' ) ); ?>
                                        </span>

                                        <span class="post-comments">
                                            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                                            <a href="<?php echo get_comments_link( $post->ID ); ?>">
                                                <?php comments_number( '0' , '1' , '%' ); ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>

                                        <span class="post-views">
                                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                                            <?php //echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <?php $count++; }
                    } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.